# How to rename files in bash script

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I've a collection of folders (>=50) under /media/user/docs with the following naming convention:

```
[2001] xxx 1
[2002] yyy
zzz
```

I would like to write a bash script to rename those folders into this format:

```
xxx 1 (2001)
yyy (2002)
zzz
```

How can I achieve by using the rename or any other Linux commands?  My working environment is Ubuntu 14.04.  Thank you.

Comment: Do they have extensions?

Comment: Sorry, those are folders, not files

Comment: You know there is tools for that, using command line checkout `mmv` and my answer, using GUI have a look at [easytag](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG/Screenshots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `mv`:

```
$ ls -d [*
[2001] yyy 2    [2002] xxx 1
```

do :

```
for i in [*; do
      new=$(echo $i | tr "[|]" "(|)" | awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" "; print $1}');
      mv "$i" "$new"; 
done

$ ls -d *\)
xxx 1 (2002)    yyy 2 (2001)
```

It replaces `[]` by `()` with `tr`, and then switches the column with `awk` for each file starting with a `[`.

Hope this helps

---

If it was file, and not folder :

And if you have more than 1 white-space and extension :

```
for i in [*.ext; do
      new=$(echo ${i%.*} | tr "[|]" "(|)" | awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" "; print $1}');
      mv "$i" "$new.ext"; 
done
```

it will transform filename `[2002] yyy 1.ext` to  `yyy 1 (2002).ext`

Comment: If the folder name is "[2001] test 2", it will be renamed as "test (2001)" which is incorrect.

Comment: @justinw yes, you're right, but it wasn't in your example, I can't guess, edit your question and detail how the filename could look like.

Answer (score 3):

Given a file with this content:

```
$ cat a
[2001] xxx
[2002] yyy
zzz
```

This replaces it the way you want, by using back reference (and escaping `[` and `]`):

```
$ sed 's/\[\([0-9]*\)\] \(\w*\)$/\2 (\1)/' a
xxx (2001)
yyy (2002)
zzz
```

So that you can use [`rename`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rename) exactly the same way:

```
rename 's/\[\([0-9]*\)\] \(\w*\)$/\2 (\1)/' *
            ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
               |            |     print them back
        catch numbers      catch words
```

Comment: This solution is not feasible if there are more than 50 folders in the directory to concatenate (cat)

Comment: Carefule, `rename` could be one of three or four different programs, see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030#Nonstandard_tools

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez and hence the downvote? Uhms. Well, it worked pretty fine in my computer and supposedly in the OPs also (despite the too many files error that I guess he got). Good to know, though, the existance of multiple `rename` tools.

Comment: Being aware of the non-portability your sole answer is "it works on me and OP"? Adding a warning to your answer would be better

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez read my comment again and you'll find out I wasn't aware of the existence of multiple rename tools. Updated to indicate it, as you are right it is good to indicate so, when known.

Answer (score 1):

## Super simple solution

Use [`mmv` package](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/mmv-copy-append-link-move-multiple-files-under-linux-shell-bash-by-wildcard-patterns-p5/).

```
mmv -r '\[*\]\ *' '#2 (#1)'
```

### Details

It's a bit complex as you need to escape square brackets, here is a [short explanation](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=mmv%20-r%20%27%5C[*%5C]%5C%20*%27%20%27%232%20%28%231%29%27).

Note that `-r` is necessary to rename directories.

#### Before

```
ls -1 ./
  [2001] xxx
  [2002] yyy
  zzz
```

#### After

```
ls -1 ./
  xxx (2001)
  yyy (2002)
  zzz
```

Comment: This package looks useful, thanks for the recommendation.  I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This would work with or without filename extensions:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ BASH_VERSINFO -ge 4 ]] || exit 1  ## Let's make minimum Bash version to 4.0.

shopt -s nullglob

for F in "$PREFIX"*; do
    read A B <<< "${F##*/}"
    [[ $A == \[*\] && -n $B && -d $F ]] || continue
    A=${A:1:${#A} - 2}
    X=''
    if [[ $B =~ (.[^. ]+)+$ ]]; then
        X=$BASH_REMATCH
        B=${B:0:${#B} - ${#X}}
    fi
    echo mv -- "$F" "${PREFIX}${B} ($A)$X"
done
```

Remove `echo` after dry-run.

This is the result of a test:

```
mv -- /var/tmp/test/[2001] A /var/tmp/test/A (2001)
mv -- /var/tmp/test/[2001] B.txt /var/tmp/test/B (2001).txt
mv -- /var/tmp/test/[2001] C.txt.gz /var/tmp/test/C (2001).txt.gz
```

`-d $F` makes it sure that only directories are processed. Change to `-f $F` if you want to target files, or just remove the expression instead if both are wanted.

Comment: The `$` sign in `[[ ]]` is not necessary :)